# Rails: save doesn't update record if called twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Using a rails console I create a Model record, then retrieve using a new variable and update some fields:

```
var = MyModel.new
var.name = "my name"
var.save

var2 = MyModel.last
var2.name = "your name"
var2.save
```

now going back to the old variable `var.save` simply returns `true` and won't overwrite the `name` field to its value: `"my name"`

Why's that?

Comment: Perhaps you are not saving over the right record? Try `var2 = MyModel.last`

Comment: Johnny Grass is probably right.  For additional debugging, take a look in log/development.log, it will have all of the SQL statements being executed and may help you better understand what is happening.

Comment: I'm trying to save over the exact same record.  More info: if I change  `var.name` to something else, then run `var.save` it properly calls the SQL UPDATE command.  This only happens if `var` remains unchanged.  It seems like something is keeping track of the state of `var` and `var.save` does nothing if the state doesn't change.  My question is: how come it checks the state of `var` rather than the state of the record in `MyModel` that `var` represents?

Comment: What was outputted to `stderr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails Models are ['Dirty'](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) by default, meaning that attribute setting functions, `attribute=()`, mark the attribute as changed and tell Rails to update this attribute on the next save. This info is stored on the model, NOT in the database. On `var.save`, Rails only updates attributes it knows to have changed. Rails does not check the database for a discrepancy if it thinks nothing has changed (this would be incredibly slow in a production environment).

You can use `var.reload` to reload attributes from the database into the corresponding object.

EDIT: To clarify the comments being made above, you should be using `MyModel.last` not `MyModel.first` in your test code. If you have more than one row in your database, `MyModel.first` will not refer to the most recently saved object, and therefore `var2` and `var` will refer to completely different objects.

Comment: Got it, thanks!  Also the `last` vs `first` issue makes sense, I was just referring to this dummy example with only one entry but I'll edit